# Error compiling the linux kernel 3.8.0

Tags: linux, kernel, compile

I am trying to compile the Linux kernel on my virtual machine which is installed Lubuntu, and I am getting the following error:

```
 In file included from ubuntu/aufs/aufs.h:45:0,
         from ubuntu/aufs/module.c:25:ubuntu/aufs/file.h:
 In function ‘au_vm_prfile_set’:ubuntu/aufs/file.h:289:5: error:
 ‘struct vm_area_struct’ has no member named ‘vm_prfile’
 make[3]: *** [ubuntu/aufs/module.o]Error 1
 make[2]: *** [ubuntu/aufs] Error 2
 make[1]: *** [ubuntu] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

That was a bug, you need to apply [aufs3.12 mmap patch](http://sourceforge.net/p/aufs/aufs3-standalone/ci/aufs3.12/tree/aufs3-mmap.patch) added "**vm_prfile**":

```
....
@@ -213,6 +213,7 @@ struct vm_region {
unsigned long vm_top; /* region allocated to here */
unsigned long vm_pgoff; /* the offset in vm_file corresponding to vm_start */
struct file *vm_file; /* the backing file or NULL */
+ **struct file *vm_prfile**; /* the virtual backing file or NULL */
```